# Linking the model in weka with c#

Tags: c#, java, weka

I am working on model that build in Weka "Model1.model", then when I run my application in c# using this statement
weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("Model1.model");

I get this error
***Unable to cast object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to type 'weka.core.FastVector'.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem.

I built a MLP model using Weka, and saved this as MLPModel.model.

When I try to read it in C# code below:

```
weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron cl = (weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron)weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("..\\..\\MLPModel.model");
```

It outputs the following error: **Unable to cast object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to type 'weka.core.FastVector'**.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Weka 3.7 to build your model?

Try building your model using Weka 3.6.

Hope this helps.